# Is there a way to connect to the DAM repository without using REST API?

Tags: magnolia

I am writing an external Java app to connect to the Magnolia CMS to allow my external application to push/pull assets into the repository.

```
Repository repository = JcrUtils.getRepository(URI);
```

What should the URI be? Assume that magnoliaAuthor is accessible on http://localhost:8080/magnoliaAuthor

Answer (score 1):

I assume you try to fetch content outside of JCR, then you should take the Resource files app as an example since it renders content outside of JCR as well.

https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS61/Resource+Files+app

If not, please let me know where that utility class come from. I cannot find it in the codebase.

Cheers,

Hope that helps,

Comment: JcrUtils is part of the Jackrabbit API available on org.apache.jackrabbit.commons.JcrUtils. I am trying to use an external app to push content into the Magnolia repository using Jackrabbit APIs. Not sure if this is possible.

Comment: Not possible to access magnolia owned repo over jcr from outside of JVM running Magnolia itself. Magnolia opens repo exclusively just for itself. Work aounds are either using rest api linked above or cluster JCR repo having magnolia to own one node of the cluster and your app the other, but that is overkill and complicates deployment for most cases out there.

Comment: Thanks @Jan for your reply. This is what I expected.